# best way to compare float numbers in this math formula

Tags: php, math

I have a code and I know it has problem with float numbers.

Please somebody write the whole code without float problems...

```
if ($x2 - $x1 !== 0.0) 
{
    $pq = ($y1 - $y2) / ($x1 - $y1);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some example of the problems you are getting?

Comment: please elaborate the question and and problem and the expected output

Comment: Please somebody write the whole code without float problems->stack is not a free coding service. hire a developer and he will do it for you'

Comment: I suggest the very interesting paper: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic, by David Goldberg, in pdf](https://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf) or [its html version on docs.oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) or [the simplified html version floating-point-gui.de](https://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: the `abs()` function is for calculating with float numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the most correct way to compare floating point values.

You can use a smallest acceptable difference:

```
if (abs(($x2-$x1)/$x1) < 0.00001) {
  //Do something 
}
```